# Windows 10 machine periodically shows Wi-Fi as "no internet available", even though other devices work fine. How to debug?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm using a brand new Dell laptop with Windows 10, connected to a WiFi network. Periodically the machine indicates the Wifi connection as "no Internet available", at which point I cannot even log into the router's admin page. Reconnecting to the Wifi usually helps restore connectivity. All other devices are working fine.

How do I debug this issue to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: This has been an issue since Vista, who knows what causes it.

Comment: You need to narrow down the problem, e.g. what happens if you ping the router?

Comment: What's the OS version of your windows 10? 1909 or 2004?What's the result when you run network diagnostics? Please try to repair internet connection using windows network diagnostics.